# Converting imported data into a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data imported like this:

```
data10 = {{"0.0141666666666667,3.094"}, {"0.0475,3.414"}, 
{"0.0808333333333333,3.624"}, 
    {"0.114166666666667,3.764"}, {"0.1475,3.9"}, 
{"0.180833333333333,4.014"}, 
    {"0.214166666666667,4.124"}, {"0.2475,4.224"}, 
{"0.280833333333333,4.318"}, 
    {"0.314166666666667,4.414"}, {"0.3475,4.514"}, 
{"0.380833333333333,4.62"}}
```

and more data. I want to use them in `NonlinearModelFit` which needs to be given a list of pairs.

```
{{0.0141666666666667,3.094}, {0.0475,3.414}, 
{0.0808333333333333,3.624}, {0.114166666666667,3.764}, 
{0.1475,3.9}, {0.180833333333333,4.014}, 
{0.214166666666667,4.124}, {0.2475,4.224}}
```

in other word how can I remove the quote marks automatically? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica! 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `data = ToExpression[ToString[data10]]`

Comment: @Coolwater, make your Comment an answer, please.

Comment: Works well thanks

Comment: How did you import the data?  How the original data looks like ?

Answer (score 5):

One of the really nice features of Mathematica is it's ability to apply user defined rules.

Starting with your data

```
data10 = {{"0.0141666666666667,3.094"}, {"0.0475,3.414"}, 
{"0.0808333333333333,3.624"}, 
    {"0.114166666666667,3.764"}, {"0.1475,3.9"}, 
{"0.180833333333333,4.014"}, 
    {"0.214166666666667,4.124"}, {"0.2475,4.224"}, 
{"0.280833333333333,4.318"}, 
    {"0.314166666666667,4.414"}, {"0.3475,4."62"}}
```

This can easily be converted to a list of numbers with this rule:

```
data10 /. {x_String} -> {ToExpression[x]}
```

Describing this in English it says:

Look through data10 and, everywhere where a list containing a string is found, replace the string with `ToExpression[string]`.

The function `ToExression` converts a string into a regular *Mathematica* expression.

Answer (score 1):

This function will transform each string into a pair of numbers:

```
    g[x_] := Module[{ch = Characters[x[[1]]]},
  pos = Position[ch, ","][[1, 1]];
  ToExpression /@ 
   StringJoin /@ {ch[[1 ;; pos - 1]], ch[[pos + 1 ;; Length[ch]]]}
  ]
```

such that

```
g[{"0.0141666666666667,3.094"}]

(*  {0.0141667, 3.094}  *)
```

Now it may be mapped onto the list:

```
    g /@ data10

(*  {{0.0141667, 3.094}, {0.0475, 3.414}, {0.0808333, 3.624}, {0.114167, 
  3.764}, {0.1475, 3.9}, {0.180833, 4.014}, {0.214167, 
  4.124}, {0.2475, 4.224}, {0.280833, 4.318}, {0.314167, 
  4.414}, {0.3475, 4.514}, {0.380833, 4.62}}  *)
```

Have fun!